# RBG light points out of nowhere

Tags: lighting

[image: glitched lighting]

[image: still glitched, but differently]

So basically I added 3 area lights with different values to create a smooth intensity change from side to side and there are those 3 weird points. They are different on each render, sometimes they don't appear and sometimes they do and it's hard to tell what it depends on. Those two renders are made one after another, without changing anything (on the second one they are more subtle, above my character). Does anyone know what might it be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you kindly attach your .blend file?

Comment: Maybe update your GPU drivers? It looks like some kind of OpenGL error.

Comment: After I played a little with my area lights and changed fog settings, lights suddenly stopped showing and I didn't even noticed at which point, so it's hard to say what caused them. I was too absorbed by trying to fix it and accidentaly oversaved that state of my work, when it was a problem so I cannot give you my blend file. I don't think that drivers were the problem though.
Some days ago I thought I saw something similar in different blend but I just ignored, so I'm gonna pay attention now, examine it if they appear again and continue to seek for explanation to them, by now I have no clue.

Comment: This is most likely the following issue: https://developer.blender.org/T77202

Comment: @RobertGützkow Yep, it's exaclly what happenes in my blend with a difference that mine is not an animation so I can just render again, hoping that they won't show up this time. 

So it's drivers that should be guilty of those artifacts. Also, looks like it only affect Eevee engine. I guess it's all we got now, just need to wait for Nvidia to do the job and fix it although it has been 2 years already since that problem exists so... yeah. I want to belive in the Green Team, but it might take them a while